# Object appears on top of post by default

Tags: javascript, blogger

so I am running a Blogger blog and I have just stumbled upon a website that has this code that makes it so that when you insert the tag  inside your post's html code, it will display the ad unit.

The code that makes it all work is this:

```
<div expr:id='"aim1" + data:post.id'></div>

<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0">
    <!-- Your Ad code here -->
</div>

<div expr:id='"aim2" + data:post.id'>
    <data:post.body/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var obj0=document.getElementById("aim1<data:post.id/>");
var obj1=document.getElementById("aim2<data:post.id/>");
var s=obj1.innerHTML;
var r=s.search(/\x3C!-- adsense --\x3E/igm);
if(r>0) {obj0.innerHTML=s.substr(0,r);obj1.innerHTML=s.substr(r+16);}
</script>
```

So the problem is that if I don't insert a `<!-- adsense -->` comment inside the post's html, the ad unit will display on top of the post right below the title by default. I do not want it to do that.

What do I need to change? I've tried changing and removing some lines but it either ends up in disasters or I somehow break the code and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: how is it related to regex ?

Comment: Someone told me the bottom parts are regex. Sorry I am a total newbie.

Comment: do you have <!-- adsense -- > written somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, when I put it on the post's html and then publish it, the ad unit appears where I placed the <!-- adsense --> so it works succesfully. The problem is when I don't paste it, then it goes on top of the post by default.

Comment: the comment <! -- adsense -- > works as an identifier here . Why do you want to remove it? if you want to change it you can directly change it in the comment and add a similar regex in the code to match

Comment: I am planning on including the comment on every post but there are nearly 100 published and on each post I need to carefully choose the area in which I want to place the ad unit so it will take some time. While I'm working on placing the comment, the other unfinished posts will have the ad unit on top where I have images and I am afraid that kind of placement near images is against Google's placement policies and might get my account disabled. That is why I want to make sure that while I finish all of the posts, no ad unit will ever appear on the top.

Comment: The location you are choosing to put adsense comment will always be the same or changed in each post?

Comment: I need to add the comment manually on the spot I want it to appear. The spots I need to target are text spots where no images appear near.